# Display all data from Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase

[image]

How can I retrieve all data from these keys and display it in recycle view. Each key has a value that I want to display.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: stackoverflow is not a site to provide direct solution, provide code for what you tried and where you are stuck

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is how you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a ValueEventListener to correct child

```
database.child("user details").addValueEventListener(...
```

would do it. You might want to consider changing "user details" to one word, eg. "userDetails".

Comment: If it must be `User details` with a space and it's only for android you can use the @PropertyName(String) to name the variable something different, or just use a Map.